# How to loop through this data?

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to get the term id from this data returned by `get_terms_by()`

```
WP_Term Object ( [term_id] => 29 [name] => gps [slug] => gps [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 29 [taxonomy] => post_tag [description] => [parent] => 0 [count] => 1 [filter] => raw )
 WP_Term Object ( [term_id] => 16 [name] => joystick [slug] => joystick [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 16 [taxonomy] => post_tag [description] => [parent] => 0 [count] => 3 [filter] => raw )
 WP_Term Object ( [term_id] => 14 [name] => lcd [slug] => lcd [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 14 [taxonomy] => post_tag [description] => [parent] => 0 [count] => 3 [filter] => raw )
```

but it returns the data in the form of a string

```
$data = get_term_by('name', $tag , 'post_tag');
print_r($data);

foreach ($data as $tag_id) {
    echo $tag_id['term_id'];
}
```

I want this `[term_id] => 29`
only term_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `get_term_by` has a parameter called `$output`. If you specify it you should get an array back:

```
$term = get_term_by( 'name', $tag, 'post_tag' );

if ( $term ) {
    echo $term->term_id;
}
else {
    echo 'Term not found';
}
```

Comment: You should get an array back, then you can get the term id using `$data['term_id']`. There's no need to use `foreach`

Comment: but it returns these three different id in one line like a string :291614. I need singe id at once inside loop body to process it further.

Comment: Can you post the full response in your question?

Comment: actually i need tags id's of specific tags according to tag name parameter passed in get_term_by() . It returns string in result and if i use this $data['term_id'] it return all id's like a string 291614. Whereas i need it sepratly. In this string 29 is seprate id 16 is the other one and 14 is the other one.

Comment: That method doesn't return a string. Can you print_ the result and paste that in your answer? Then I can tell you how to loop over it

Comment: The documentation states that this function will only return a single term: "If $value does not exist, the return value will be false. If $taxonomy exists and $field and $value combinations exist, the Term will be returned." I would recommend getting a term by it's slug so you're sure that the query you're searching for is unique. I updated my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you cant get just `[term_id] => 291` because you have 3 terms in result, you can have array `$term_ids = array(29, 16, 14);`

```
$data = get_term_by('name', $tag , 'post_tag');
$term_ids = array();

foreach ($data as $term) {
    $term_ids[] = $term->term_id;
}

print_r($term_ids);
```

Comment: Output:Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => [7] => [8] => [9] => ) Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => [7] => [8] => [9] => ) Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => [7] => [8] => [9] => )